# Why it is not passing if this if statement

Tags: ios4, xcode4.4

I am making a calculator, and I defined all functions SUM SUB DIV MUL

Then when I typed this if statement is pass for only the first one
although the condition is wrong

So what I have is 2 text fields
4 actions for each button
2 actions : result and clear
and a label for the operation which will take + or - or * or ÷ whatever ...
this label called Operation

I typed this if statement in the calculate action, but I don't know what is the wrong.
When I tap calculate the operation will be the first if operation which is +

and when I press 1 -4 it shows 1 + 4 = 5

```
 //in -(IBAction)calculate :

-(IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender{
if (operation.text=@"+"){
//sum
a =num1.text.integerValue;
b= num2.text.integerValue;
c=num1.text.integerValue+num2.text.integerValue;
printf("%i >> %i",b,num2.text.integerValue);
[num1 resignFirstResponder];
[num2 resignFirstResponder];
result.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i + %i = %i",a,b,c];}

 else if (operation.text=@"-"){
//sub
a =num1.text.integerValue;
b= num2.text.integerValue;
c=num1.text.integerValue-num2.text.integerValue;
printf("%i >> %i",b,num2.text.integerValue);
[num1 resignFirstResponder];
[num2 resignFirstResponder];
    result.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i - %i = %i",a,b,c];}

else if (operation.text=@"*"){
//mul
a =num1.text.integerValue;
b= num2.text.integerValue;
c=num1.text.integerValue*num2.text.integerValue;
printf("%i >> %i",b,num2.text.integerValue);
[num1 resignFirstResponder];
[num2 resignFirstResponder];
result.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i * %i = %i",a,b,c];
}

//div
else if (operation.text=@"÷"){
a =num1.text.integerValue;
b= num2.text.integerValue;
c=num1.text.integerValue/num2.text.integerValue;
printf("%i >> %i",b,num2.text.integerValue);
[num1 resignFirstResponder];
[num2 resignFirstResponder];
result.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i ÷ %i = %i",a,b,c];
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` performs assignment, so `if (operation.text=@"+")` actually assigns `@"+"` to `operation.text`, it does not compare for equality. The assigned value then is treated as true by the `if` statement.

Comment: Start by reading a good book on Objective C ? You can't learn a programming language by guesswork.

Comment: Try `[operation.text isEqualToString:@"+"]`.